# Error in paramaterised constructor

Tags: java

When we are using parametrized constructor it is giving error, but when we are using default constructor it is not giving any error, why?

```
import java.io.*;

public class PrimeGenerator
{
    final int a;
    PrimeGenerator(PrimeGenerator r)
    {
        r.a=10; 
    }

    public static void main(String rgs[])
    {
        PrimeGenerator ab= new PrimeGenerator(ab);
        System.out.println(ab.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please not SHOUT AT US?

Comment: Correct the title and why are you using capital letters?

Answer (score 3):

`ab` is not initialized when you are attempting to pass it into the constructor.

```
PrimeGenerator ab = new PrimeGenerator(ab);
```

You need to initialize a `PrimeGenerator` first and then pass into a constructor later on.

---

I'm not entirely sure what your goal is here, but as Rudi mentioned you need to initialize final variables before the constructor finishes.

Here is a possible solution to your problem to address: initializes before passing as parameter and final initialization.

```
public class PrimeGenerator{
    final int a;

    PrimeGenerator(){
        a = 10;
    }

    PrimeGenerator(PrimeGenerator r){
        a = r.a; 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        PrimeGenerator ab = new PrimeGenerator();
        PrimeGenerator cd = new PrimeGenerator(ab);
        System.out.println(ab.a);
        System.out.println(cd.a);
    }
}
```

*Note:* The accepted convention is to name the String[] in the `main` `args`.

Comment: +1, although I would say this is their **main** problem, it still wouldn't work because their final int variable a has not been initialized before the constructor finishes.

Comment: Why would the String[] in main have to be named args? If I remeber correctly, java looks for a `public static void main` that takes a `String[]` as parameter. Since there can be no two such methods, the name of the string array shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Pphoenix I looked this up and you're right, however I believe my IDE complained about having it named `rgs`.  Will test in a few hours when I'm at that machine.

Comment: @Andrew_CS I assume that args is the naming convention though. It must be hard to come up with a better short variable name than args for arguments :)

Comment: @Pphoenix It is the naming convention, I edited the answer.  Not sure why I thought my IDE complained about it, it's not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

One of your issues is because your class variable `a` is declared `final`.

A `final` variable must be initialized before the constructor finishes running. You're not doing this because you're trying to initialize the `a` variable of the `PrimeGenerator` parsed into your constructor instead of the `a` variable in `this` `PrimeGenerator`.

Also, as pointed out by Andrew_CS, you haven't initialized the `ab` variable **before** trying to parse it into your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `a` is final, meaning that you can only set its value once, when creating it. Thus, `r.a=10;` will fail since a cannot be set twice.

Also, you cannot send an object to itself since it is not yet created.

Answer (score 0):

You add the object as parameter, that you create. that can't work:

```
PrimeGenerator ab= new PrimeGenerator(ab);
```

use the default constructor.

```
PrimeGenerator()
{
a=10; 
}
```